# Unable to connect to my server

Tags: linux, mysql, port-forwarding

I'm unable to connect to my own server, which has a MySQL database which I want to access.
I correctly opened the 3306 port on the router and called my internet provider that confirmed so.
But when I try `telnet x.xxx.xxx.x 3306` it stucks on

> Trying x.xxx.xxx.x...

Same with traceroute command, the route seems to go till my PC and then find some blockage and it's unable to reach it.

I checked if there is some firewall, but as far as I am aware there aren't.

If I run on my server `telnet localhost 3306` it correctly connects.

Comment: On your server you have probably started firewall. Enable your IP in firewall and try again.

Comment: is your public IP address between `100.64.0.0` and `100.127.255.255` by any chance? (doesn't look like it with that `x.xxx.xxx.x` pattern ... but have to ask anyway) ... what does `correctly opened the 3306 port` mean? what does "opened" mean?

Comment: @RomeoNinov How can I check if there is some firewall? I'm mounting linux mint and using `ufw status` it gives me **State: Inactive**

Comment: @JaromandaX No it is between thos IP addresses. I forwarded the port 3306 on my router, and like I said also my internet provider told me that the port is opened correctly.

Comment: Oh wait - are you trying to connect to public x.x.x.x:3306 from within your LAN? If so, perhaps you've port forwarded, but have you hair-pinned (assuming your router is capable)

Comment: No i'm not in a LAN. I'm getting crazy about this. Something blocks the connection. I can't wrap my head around it :)

Answer (score 1):

you should check if your mysql server instance is listening on your machine ip address and not just on your localhost (127.0.0.1).

you can verify it in two ways:

1. search in your mysql configuration  **bind-address** option ( on many distro it /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf ) since by default mysql daemon bind itself on 127.0.0.1 and so it's not reaceable outside your machine.
2. use a command like **ss -pl |grep 3306** in order to check on which ip your mysql instace is binded to.

Comment: I already changed bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0
But when I use telnet I can see the problem is before mysql. There is something the blocks the connection before.